# SMD diode part number from marking code

Tags: surface-mount, code

I can't find SMD diode part no from Marking code,pls suggest if possible.[image]

Comment: thats because those codes generally say nothing much about it and are not meant for these identification purposes

Comment: How big is it ?

Comment: Remove it from the board and try measuring the forward voltage drop

Comment: sir it is SOD23

Comment: @dim it is not necessary to mark this as a duplicate question, the link provided is related, but not a duplicate

Comment: @laptop Well, this question here is vague enough and yours is generic enough that I still think it can be considered a duplicate. Just like every vague question that looks like "Can I use a 5V/2A adapter instead of a 5V/1.5A" gets marked as a dupe to https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/34745/choosing-power-supply-how-to-get-the-voltage-and-current-ratings/34746.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is:  CMOZ43L in SOD523, marking R1 found here: https://www.centralsemi.com/get_document.php?cmp=1&mergetype=pd&mergepath=pd&pdf_id=CMOZ2L4_SERIES.PDF

Comment: Sir it is SOD23